# Relocation and cost of living

Tags: relocation

My company has two offices both in the US. Their headquarters are in a different state that is not very close to my office. The HQ has decided to close my office and offer the ability to relocate. I am all for it. However, i have been looking for apartments and realize that the places i have been looking at are a few hundred dollars more than what I pay now. To make matters complicated, i just passed my 3 month probationary. In this type of scenario, is it uncommon to ask for a pay increase citing the relocation as the reason? If it is, when would be an appropriate time to ask for a pay increase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In this type of scenario, is it uncommon to ask for a pay increase
>   citing the relocation as the reason?

In this scenario it is common to be offered a salary adjustment to cover the increase in the cost of living. Consider all factors, not just rent.

A site like this could help: http://www.bestplaces.net/cost-of-living/

> If it is, when would be an appropriate time to ask for a pay increase?

Ask before you agree to relocate. Preferably as soon as possible. That way, you'll have your answer and can plan appropriately.

As @DeNaeL wisely points out, get any agreements or statement about salary changes in writing before you agree to relocation.

Comment: They offered same salary but one of the higherups mentioned everythings negotiable

Comment: Get any agreements or statement about salary changes in writing before you agree to relocation.